# Android Device Stolen, Android Device Manager not set up

Tags: remote-control, remote-access

My android device has been stolen (Xperia L) and I had not set up Android Device Manager. How do I remove the google access and play store; uninstall apps; protect SD card and personal data; sign out from shopping apps and block the SIM access.

If there is a way to control my phone remotely **without** having any prior access to the device or Android Device Manager enabled, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Even phones where I never installed Android Device Manager are listed for me on google.com/android/devicemanager so I think as long as you are signed in to the Google services you'd be able to use the Device Manager.

Comment: But the mobiole phone is switched off, so it is just showing my phone and keeps saying "Contacting Your Phone" and after few minutes it shows "Location Unavailable". If it is another way then please help. Thanks

Comment: It's not impossible to control a phone that is turned off or not connected to the internet I'm afraid. What you could do is get the IMEI blocked, you can find your phones IMEI on google.com/settings/dashboard (unfold the arrow next to "Android"). Contact your service provider and give the IMEI to them. This won't prevent the thief from using your phone completely but they won't be able to use your phones cellular network.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote phone is **off**, or if it does **not have network access**, you won't be able to control it remotely. If the SIM card is not removed, you *could* control it via SMS *if* you set up an app to do certain security functions (with apps like [AVG Antivirus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antivirus)). However, *remote control from SMS is limited and you need to set it up in advance*.

If you did not set up such security measures, there is no way to remotely access your device without network access. Since Android Device Manager doesn't work, **we can conclude that the phone has no network access, or it is off**.

At this point, although you cannot control your device remotely, you might be able to find out it's last reported location from Google's [**Location Timeline**](https://www.google.com/maps/timeline). This would be able to help you locate it if you did not turn off *location history* on your device.

If you do locate your device, please do not attempt to confront any suspect by yourself.

*From [Lookout Mobile Security:](https://www.lookout.com/resources/know-your-mobile/what-to-do-if-your-phone-is-stolen)*

> If your cell phone is lost or stolen and you don’t have a mobile security app, the first thing to do is contact your network provider, who will be able to block your phone in order to stop anyone else from using it.
>
> This is particularly important if you have a pay monthly contract, as you will be liable for any calls made (or expensive apps downloaded) before you report your phone stolen.
>   Most of the major US network providers allow you to suspend your service and request a new SIM online or by calling their customer service department.
>
> If your cell phone has been stolen it's also important to notify the police, as insurance providers will usually need a crime reference number in order to process any claims.
>
> If you use your smartphone to shop or bank, you may also need a police report to dispute any fraudulent charges made on your debit or credit card accounts using the stolen device.
>
> Make a report at your local station, being sure to give them your device's International Mobile Equipment Identity (IMEI) number, which your network should be able to provide you with. This could help the police get your phone back to you if it were to be recovered.